# Data List with Horizontal Layout and select functionlity

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I want to display records  in Horizontal Layout. I used Data List control for the same which displays only 5 records.

I want select functionality so that when i click the items in Data List , complete details will be displayed in another page.

Thanks a lot.

```
 <div style="margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 5%">
        <asp:DataList ID="dlTop5" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatColumns="5"
           ItemStyle-Width="40%" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="3" style="margin-left: 3%">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgServant" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("photo")%>' Height="150px"
                                Width="150px" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name")%>' Font-Bold="true"
                                ForeColor="BlueViolet"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("phone")%>' ForeColor="BlueViolet"> </asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSrno" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sysno")%>'> </asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnViewMore" runat="server" Text="View More" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear and it seems that what you desire is quite elaborate. With what in particular are you experiencing issues? What have you tried already, it would be good to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Basically, I want how i can achieve  button click event for the  items  in ItTemplate and Footer template. On click of image button, Detail page needs be opened which display complete details. Similarly on Click of View Button, all records to be displayed in Grid View (presently i am showing only 5 records)

Comment: Please edit your actual question post to more clearly describe your issue. If not it is very unlikely you will get solid answers from the community. Also consider revising your title to be more descriptive. I am not an expert but something like "asp.net usercontrol update record view on click"

Comment: I got solution for the same. I added "onItemCommand" event for the Data List..

Comment: Why do we hassle posters with questions about "it's not clear" etc? To me, it is clear. To you it may not be. Please read between the lines and see that it's a basic - how to list something and be able to click it to do something else. A little bit of lateral thinking goes a long way

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do ...

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" GridLines="Both" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RollCallPeriod") %>' OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ATCNTV1ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT RollCallPeriod FROM tblBoardingRollCallPeriods">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And use the **OnClick** event to fire up a call into your code behind to reveal a panel for example and put all your specific code about the selection inside the panel - ie: Gridview, etc.

You don't have to use a LinkButton of course. It can be anything you want - a button, a hyperlink, etc

Labels do not have OnClick etc. Unless you "trap" them using JavaScript like mouseclick or mouseover.